# Site not displaying in iframe due to CSP violation

Tags: iframe, content-security-policy

I'm seeing this error in Chrome for an iframe:
Refused to display 'https://secure.entertimeonline.com/ta/7687.careers?careersSearch=1&HostedBy=atticangel.org&InFrameset=1' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors file: cdvfile: 'self' https://atticangel.org".

This is the code for the iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://secure.entertimeonline.com/ta/7687.careers?careersSearch=1&HostedBy=atticangel.org&InFrameset=1" width="100%" height="900" frameborder="1"> </iframe>
```

You can see the error in action here: https://www.atticangel.org/work-here/job-openings

I'm not super familiar with CSP directives, and am not finding information in particular about what a cdvfile is. My question is, is there anything I can change on my site to meet the security policy? Apparently this page was previously working (I did not build this page, but I am supporting it now), so I'm not sure if something changed with this site that I am supporting, or with the remote site.

Comment: Here is the code for the iframe:
<iframe src="https://secure.entertimeonline.com/ta/7687.careers?careersSearch=1&HostedBy=atticangel.org&InFrameset=1" width="100%" height="900" frameborder="1"> </iframe>

Comment: The CSP for the iframe source: `default-src 'self' gap://ready; script-src 'self' gap://ready www.google-analytics.com *.google.com *.googleapis.com *.taxcreditco.com *.linkedin.com *.youtube.com; frame-src 'self' gap://ready www.google-analytics.com *.google.com *.googleapis.com *.taxcreditco.com *.linkedin.com *.youtube.com; img-src * data:; media-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-ancestors file: cdvfile: 'self' https://atticangel.org`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSP allows atticangel.com, but your URL is www.atticangel.com.

If you drop the "www." it works: https://atticangel.org/work-here/job-openings

...so I would suggest adding `www.atticangel.com` to your frame-ancestors CSP

Comment: incidentally, I would suggest actively deciding if this site's URL has "www." or not, and make it so the "wrong" one redirects to the one you've chosen.